# store a data as a json string in nosql using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, neo4j, nosql

for a given Model i've got the `Post model` a `$fillable` attribute where i've define a list a attibutes like this:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'slug',
        'body',
        'type',
        'status',
        'inputs',
    ];
```

In the user interface for some reasons there will,there are some customfield that i would like to store as `string` in the 'inputs' attrbute.Here is my controller:

```
public function store(StorePost $request){
    $data=$request->validate();
    $p=Post::create($data);
    return response()->json(PostResource::collection($p)); 
}
```

But the thing is that,for the attribute `input`,would like it value to be a `json string` as there are some custom fields and data will also come from the `form` and all their names will be prefixed by `input_` like for example :`input_body,input_slug,input_title`.But i there are not defined in the model,so what i would like to do is to create a paire-key value from them in the controller in the following structure :

```
[
    custom_field_name1=>value1,
    custom_field_name2=>value2
]
```

But has the there names will depend on the user that will created them,i dont know how to have a controller how can identifiy them automatically to create the array above.the then converts them in a `json string` to store them in the `input` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

**In Mysql do like that**

first of all update input field string to json field in migration using `->json()` method

```
 $table->json('inputs');
```

after add migration add in `Post` Model

```
 protected $casts = [
    'inputs' => 'array'
 ];
```

> after u cast column inputs into array automatically store data in json
>   array and retrive

for more detail [see](https://laraveldaily.com/working-with-mysql-json-columns-in-laravel-custom-properties-example/)

**IN nosql do like that**

```
 add this line in `Post` Model

 protected $casts = [
    'inputs' => 'array'
 ];
```

> cast only field into array [see](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting)

Comment: I cannot do that in migrations because i'm using a nosql database,neo4j

Comment: @ChristianLisangola u just need to  cast inputs array in post model only

Comment: But,when attributes that are comng from the form's names are not defined in the `$fillable attribute` of the `model`,how to identify them and put them in the `input array`?